# How can I fix my map width after adjusting container in Openlayers 6

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript, openlayers

**Note: this is fixed on OpenLayers 7, but I wonder how I can solve it in 6**

In OpenLayers 6, if you reduce the width of the map container and then expand it again, the complete corrected map may not load entirely. You can fix it again by adjusting your browser width, but I hope someone can find a solution to fix this issue besides upgrading to 7.

demo link:
https://codesandbox.io/s/accessible-forked-d2knlh?file=/index.html

[image: GIF that displays that map get stuck in width]

Comment: Calling `map.updateSize()` should fix it.  https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_Map-Map.html#updateSize